# Gradient of cost function

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, least-squares

I have tried to calculate the gradient of the LMS cost function as follows but have a problem.

$$J(\theta) = \frac12(y - X'\theta)^2$$
where $y$ is a scalar, theta and $X$ is a $n$ dimensional vector and $X'$ denotes tranpose of $X$.

gradient wrt $\theta$ according to me should be $(y - X'\theta)\theta$.

Is this correct? I have a doubt because opening the bracket results in an exression which involves multiplication of $X'\theta \,\theta$
which is not possible. Where have I made the mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient of $J(\theta)=\frac12 (y-X'\theta)^2$ is given by

$$\text{grad }J(\theta)=(y-X'\theta)X$$

It's of course a vector because $\theta$ is a vector too. If you don't see how it works, just compute the element-wise derivatives first.

Comment: HI thanks that was what i thought. But when open the bracket,it results the multiplication x'*theta*x! But this is not valid right..since theta*X is not a valid multiplication

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan: It is valid: you get $(X'\theta)\cdot X$ which works because $X'\theta$ is a scalar. You might also rearrange and write it as $XX'\theta$, which works regardless how you group the vectors: $(XX')\theta$ is a matrix times a vector, and $X(X'\theta)$ is a vector time a scalar, both of which of course result in the same expression.

Comment: Also note that your result is different because you have $\theta$ outside the parentheses, whereas in my answer there's $X$ outside the parentheses.

Comment: Okay those two are fine..what about the expression X'(theta*X) isnt (AB)C =   A(BC) ..

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan: That's not what you get. You get the scalar inside the parentheses times a vector: $(X'\theta)X$. If you want to rearrange, you need to do it as shown in my previous comment.

Comment: Ohh okay you cannot rearrange as i did right? That's what i wanted to know..is there some well defined rule?

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan: If the dimensions allow it, you put parentheses where you like, otherwise not. E.g., $XX'\theta$ can be computed in two ways (as shown before), but $(X'\theta)X$ can't unless you rearrange and put the vector $X$ to the left.